# Return string values from sql to javascript function

Tags: javascript, sql

I got a javascript function and i want to retrieve values from sql

**SQL** `SELECT * FROM db_menu_config` returns

```
ID : 1
parent : menu   
icon_path : codebase/imgs/
xml : common/getMenu.php
```

**Javascript**

```
function doOnLoad() {
    menu = new dhtmlXMenuObject('menu');
    menu.setIconsPath('codebase/imgs/');
    menu.enableDynamicLoading('common/menu.inc.php', true);
}
```

I want to replace `'menu'`, `'codebase/imgs/'` and `'common/menu.inc.php'` with variables from sql in order to run and be able to modify it from database without changing the script.

**Update**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON('common/json.menu.php', function (data) {
            $.each(data, function( key, val ) {
                menu = new dhtmlXMenuObject(val.parent);
                menu.setIconsPath(val.icon_path);
                menu.enableDynamicLoading(val.xml);
            });
            });
        });
```

The only problem is that if i add another record (a second), it will not work. its now right.

Comment: What serverside solutions do you use? Perhaps you'd have a PHP or similar script to form the said .js, as you can do `echo "<script>...`

Comment: I thought it but i want to use a js file with all the init functions and make it dynamic. I got php files only to generate xml and retrieve data. Not config of my structure.

Answer (score 0):

Get your values in PHP then echo them in your JS like this:

```
function doOnLoad()
{
    menu = new dhtmlXMenuObject('<?php echo $parent; ?>');
    menu.setIconsPath('<?php echo $icon_path; ?>');
    menu.enableDynamicLoading('<?php echo $xml; ?>', true);
}
```

Comment: Im on .js file. not php

Comment: @JohnPriestakos You can make *.js parsable by PHP, and put PHP code in the js file to get your vars. Make sure you'll either `require_once` proper modules that initialize the request for those vars, or call this js from a PHP module with already initialized vars.

Comment: @JohnPriestakos Oh, my bad... You should consider using ajax then, to get the values from a php file.

Comment: @Vesper im confused ! How can i do this ?

Comment: You can set the type `js` as `application/x-httpd-php` in your configs (Apache example, yours might differ), so that if the browser requests a JS, PHP engine kicks in and parses the JS as a part of PHP code, so that you can add `<?php ?>` blocks in there, initialize variables by requesting your config, and output correct results to the browser. Or, you leave the original answer's text in the JS, but instead of placing `<script src="some.js">` in the output you do `<?php include("some.js"); ?>` thus embedding the script into the webpage, and that script will have proper values in place.

Comment: @PiTiNiNjA Perhaps you should leave the original answer as a part of currently visible edition, because that approach is possible under certain conditions.

Comment: Thank you but i dont think that will work. I'll try JSON again